# Duplicate data from array

Tags: php, mysql, html

The code is:

```
<?php

// my query

if (isset($_GET['ssiptype']))
{
    if (($_GET['ssiptype']) == 'gma'){
        $query = "SELECT location, year, serviceArea, noOfBenificiaries, stat, fundingSrc, projCost 
            FROM swipdd
            WHERE fundingSrc LIKE 'GMA-Rice%' AND ssiptype = 'SWIP'" ;
    }
    elseif (($_GET['ssiptype']) == 'am'){
        $query = "SELECT location, year, serviceArea, noOfBenificiaries, stat, fundingSrc, projCost 
            FROM swipdd
            WHERE fundingSrc LIKE 'AM-Rice%' AND ssiptype = 'SWIP'" ;
    }
    elseif (($_GET['ssiptype']) == 'hvcccred'){
        $query = "SELECT location, year, serviceArea, noOfBenificiaries, stat, fundingSrc, projCost 
            FROM swipdd
            WHERE fundingSrc LIKE 'HVCC RED%' AND ssiptype = 'SWIP'" ;
    }
    elseif (($_GET['ssiptype']) == 'hvcc'){
        $query = "SELECT location, year, serviceArea, noOfBenificiaries, stat, fundingSrc, projCost 
            FROM swipdd
            WHERE fundingSrc LIKE 'HVCC%' AND ssiptype = 'SWIP'" ;
    }
    else{}
}
// output

if (isset($query))
{
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

  echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='3'>";
  echo "<tr> 
            <td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">LOCATION</td>
            <td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">YEAR</td>
            <td bgcolor=\"#DFE8EC\">STATUS</td>
        </tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

  $final_result = array_unique($row);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['location'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['year'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stat'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
  } 
  echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
//dummy data
LOCATION    YEAR   STATUS
---------------------------
park         1999   ok
----------------------------
sea          2000   fine
----------------------------
```

I'm getting this output:

```
LOCATION    YEAR   STATUS
----------------------------
park         1999   ok
----------------------------
sea          2000   fine
----------------------------
park         1999   ok
----------------------------
sea          2000   fine
----------------------------
park         1999   ok
----------------------------
sea          2000   fine
----------------------------
```

It is repeating twice. What is wrong in my code? Please, any help will be appreciated.

> Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have duplicate data in your database?

Comment: no i dont have any duplicate data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. only select the columns you need.
2. In order to not get multiple entires you need som kind of additional qualifier. Im going to assume you want the most recent year to display so what we can do is use GROUP BY to select distinct locations, and ORDER BY to get the most recent year to display
3. The code is ugly... you keep repeating the same SQL when you can jsut replace the part that changes.

So putting it all together

```
<?php 

$fundingSrcs = array(
  'gma' => 'GMA-Rice%',
  /* repeat for your other options */
);
$sql = "SELECT location, year, stat 
       FROM swipdd
       WHERE fundingSrc LIKE %s AND ssiptype = 'SWIP'
       ORDER BY year DESC
       GROUP BY location";

$result = false; // initialize as a default of false

if(isset($_GET['ssiptype']) {
   $ssitype = $_GET['ssiptype'];
   if(isset($fundingSrcs[$ssitype]) {

      // substitute the db quoted string for the %s
      $query = sprintf($sql, mysql_real_escape_string($fundingSrcs[$ssitype]));
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   }
}
?>

<?php if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)): ?>
  <table border='1' cellpadding='3'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor="#DFE8EC">LOCATION</th>
        <th bgcolor="#DFE8EC">YEAR</th>
        <th bgcolor="#DFE8EC">STATUS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['location'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['year'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['stat'] ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<?php else if($err = mysql_error()): ?>
  <p>There was an error executing this request.</p>
<?php else: ?>
  <p>No matching entries found</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: sorry for my bad coding im just starting to code in php.. thanks for ur reply .. i will try ur changes in my code thanks again dude..

Comment: `$fundingSrcs = array(
  'gma' => 'GMA-Rice%',
  /* repeat for your other options */
); `         about this part i have an error that says unknown column on where clause.. cant figure out what to do

Comment: youre getting an unknown column on `fundingSrc`? If so you can add it to the list of columns to select but that shouldnt be an issue. Post a new question with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, not `mysql_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Try asking the database for distinct data, instead of having PHP filter it down.  Emphasis on the word *distinct* (that's your cue to google...).